# Find day of date using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get day of given date using jQuery? In c# I do it like this

```
 if(MyDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

How can i do this in jQuery?

Comment: You dont need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JavaScript's Date.getDay()

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var d = new Date();

    alert(d.getDay());
  } );
```

As stated you don't need jQuery to use this but I've wrapped it in jQuery for your pleasure.
As stated by nc3b the result its 0 based where 0 is Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript, you can find the day of week: `Date.getDay();`
Say you have something like this:

```
Date d = new Date(...);
d.getDay(); // returns day of week.
```

Careful as it's zero-based so it will return from 0 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we need to build an array for this.

```
var days = [
    'SUN', //Sunday starts at 0
    'MON',
    'TUE',
    'WED',
    'THU',
    'FRI',
    'SAT'
];

d = new Date(); //This returns Wed Apr 02 2014 17:28:55 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
x = d.getDay(); //This returns a number, starting with 0 for Sunday

alert (days[x]);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/LBt2b/).